# How do I copy structure of Pst file to new pst file thru VBA macro

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I split my default PST file year wise thru VBA macro Such as New Pst File Name may be Year-2015.pst. It should contain the all the mails which are belongs to year 2015 ( all folders ).

Comment: In the normal course of events you could not expect an answer to this question here.  You ask for far too much for a single question and show no effort.  However, I have been developing a macro along the lines you require for myself.  I will post it when I finished.

Answer (score 0):

In the normal course of events, you would not have got any answer to your question.  This is not a free coding service.  This site exists to allow programmers to help one another develop.  If you post your faulty code and explain how its behaviour differs from what you seek, someone will help often within minutes on the Excel VBA but more slowly on the Outlook VBA site.

You are getting this answer because I have been coding a macro for myself which appears to match your requirement.  The comments are those I write to allow myself to return to the macro in six or twelve months and update it.  I have tested it by using it.  It has not had the systematic testing I would normally give a macro before release.  It does not delete anything so if it fails it will not do any permanent damage.  The most likely failure is that it will just stop with the VBA interpreter reporting an error.  If this happens then add a comment describing the scenario and I will attempt to fix the error.

Subroutine `CtrlMoveEmailsByYear` is the only macro you will have to rewrite. Subroutine `MoveEmailsByYear` and `function GetCreateFldr2Full` are the macros specifically coded to meet this requirement.  All other subroutines and function are general functions some of which I have used for years.

Consider subroutine `CtrlMoveEmailsByYear`:

```
Sub CtrlMoveEmailsByYear()

  Dim FldrDestRoot As Folder
  Dim FldrSrcRoot As Folder

  Set FldrSrcRoot = GetFolderRef("dell", "!Tony")

  Set FldrDestRoot = GetFolderRef("tony archive 2010")
  Call MoveEmailsByYear(FldrSrcRoot, FldrDestRoot, 2010)

  Set FldrDestRoot = GetFolderRef("tony archive 2011")
  Call MoveEmailsByYear(FldrSrcRoot, FldrDestRoot, 2011)

End Sub
```

“dell” is the name of a PST file.  I copied it to my current laptop from an earlier laptop.  “!Tony” is a folder within the PST file that contains my private emails.  “dell” contains other folders which I either do not wish to save or which I wish to save differently.

`GetFolderRef` is one of my standard routines. The first (compulsory) parameter is the user/display name of a store.  A PST file is a type of store.  The leftmost names in Outlook’s folder pane are the user/display names of stores. The second (optional) parameter is the name of a folder within the store.  There can be third, fourth, fifth parameters (up to whatever depth is required) for the names of sub and sub-sub folders.  The routine returns a reference to the named folder if it exists. I have used `GetFolderRef` to get references to “dell->!Tony”, “tony archive 2010” and “tony archive 2011”

These references are used in calls of `MoveEmailsByYear`.  Its parameters are a source folder, a destination folder and a year.  It moves all emails for the specified year from the source folder to the destination folder.  The move retains the structure.  For example, if folder “dell->!Tony-> Amazon->TraderA” contains an email from the specified year, that email will be moved to “tony archive 2010->Amazon->TraderA”.  The destination folder will be created if it does not already exist.

You will need to create an equivalent macro with appropriately constructed calls of `MoveEmailsByYear`.  The default “Inbox” is in store “outlook data file” but that may not be where your emails are held.  Use the names from your folder pane.  On my system Outlook has created a store per email account with names that match the email addresses so I have one inbox per current email account plus one per old computer.

Warning: I have dozens of macros.  I believe I have extracted every macro used by `MoveEmailsByYear` or the routines it calls.  If you get a report saying “macro Xxxxx not specified” then sorry.  Tell me and I will add it to the answer.

```
Sub MoveEmailsByYear(ByRef FldrSrcRoot As Folder, ByRef FldrDestRoot As Folder, _
                     ByVal YearToCopy As Long)

  ' FldrSrcRoot:  A folder
  ' FldrDestRoot: Another folder that cannot be in the same store.
  ' YearToCopy:   A four digit year

  ' The routine moves emails with a ReceivedTime within YearToCopy from FldrSrcRoot,
  ' or a folder under FldrSrcRoot, to the equivalent position in FldDestRoot.
  ' See function GetCreateFldr2Full for information on how the new folder is created.

  ' The restriction that FldrSrcRoot and FldrDestRoot cannot be in the same store is
  ' to avoid any possibility that FldrSrcRoot and FldrDestRoot do not overlap to an
  ' email is moved to a sub-folder within FldrDestRoot and then moved to a
  ' sub-sub-folder within FldrDestRoot and so on indefinitely.

  ‘ Coded by Tony Dallimore

  Dim FldrDestCrnt As Folder
  Dim FldrSrcCrnt As Folder
  Dim FldrSrcLast As Folder
  Dim FldrSrcCrntNames() As String
  Dim FldrSrcLastNames() As String
  Dim InxN As Long
  Dim MailItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim NewFldr As Boolean

  Set FldrSrcLast = Nothing
  Call GetNextMailItem("I", MailItemCrnt, FldrSrcCrnt, FldrSrcRoot)

  Do While Not MailItemCrnt Is Nothing
     With MailItemCrnt
       If Year(.ReceivedTime) = YearToCopy Then
         If FldrSrcLast Is Nothing Then
           ' FldrSrcLast not initialised so this is first mail item from required year
           NewFldr = True
         ElseIf FldrSrcLast <> FldrSrcCrnt Then
           ' Different folders
           NewFldr = True
         End If
         If NewFldr Then
           FldrSrcLastNames = GetFolderNames(FldrSrcCrnt)
           Set FldrDestCrnt = GetCreateFldr2Full(FldrSrcRoot, FldrSrcCrnt, FldrDestRoot)
         End If
         .Move FldrDestCrnt
       End If
     End With
     Call GetNextMailItem("N", MailItemCrnt, FldrSrcCrnt)
  Loop

End Sub

Public Sub DeNestParamArray(Denested() As Variant, ParamArray Original() As Variant)

  ' Each time a ParamArray is passed to a sub-routine, it is nested in a one
  ' element Variant array.  This routine finds the bottom level of the nesting and
  ' sets RetnValue to the values in the original parameter array so that other routines
  ' need not be concerned with this complication.

  '  Coded by Tony Dallimore

  Dim Bounds         As Collection
  Dim Inx1           As Long
  Dim Inx2           As Long
  Dim DenestedCrnt() As Variant
  Dim DenestedTemp() As Variant

  DenestedCrnt = Original
  ' Find bottom level of nesting
  Do While True
    If VarType(DenestedCrnt) < vbArray Then
      ' Have found a non-array element so must have reached the bottom level
      Debug.Assert False   ' Should have exited loop at previous level
      Exit Do
    End If
    Call NumberOfDimensions(Bounds, DenestedCrnt)
    ' There is one entry in Bounds per dimension in NestedCrnt
    ' Each entry is an array: Bounds(N)(0) = Lower bound of dimension N
    ' and Bounds(N)(1) = Upper bound of dimenssion N
    If Bounds.Count = 1 Then
      If Bounds(1)(0) > Bounds(1)(1) Then
        ' The original ParamArray was empty
        Denested = DenestedCrnt
        Exit Sub
      ElseIf Bounds(1)(0) = Bounds(1)(1) Then
        ' This is a one element array
        If VarType(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) < vbArray Then
          ' But it does not contain an array so the user only specified
          ' one value (a literal or a non-array variable)
          ' This is a valid exit from this loop
            Exit Do
        End If
        ' The following sometimes crashed Outlook
        'DenestedCrnt = DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))
        If VarType(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) = vbArray + vbString Then
          ' DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) is an array of strings.
          ' This is the array sought but it must be converted to an array
          ' of variants with lower bound = 0 before it can be returned.
          ReDim Denested(0 To UBound(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))) - LBound(DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))))
          Inx2 = LBound(DenestedCrnt)
          For Inx1 = 0 To UBound(Denested)
            Denested(Inx1) = DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))(Inx2)
            Inx2 = Inx2 + 1
          Next
          Exit Sub
        End If
        DenestedTemp = DenestedCrnt(Bounds(1)(0))
        DenestedCrnt = DenestedTemp
      Else
        ' This is a one-dimensional, non-nested array
        ' This is the usual exit from this loop
        Exit Do
      End If
    Else
      ' This is an array but not a one-dimensional array
      ' There is no code for this situation
      Debug.Assert False
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

  ' Have found bottom level array.  Save contents in Return array.
  If LBound(DenestedCrnt) <> 0 Then
    ' A ParamArray should have a lower bound of 0.  Assume the ParamArray
    ' was loaded with a 1D array that did not have a lower bound of 0.
    ' Build Denested so it has standard lbound
    ReDim Denested(0 To UBound(DenestedCrnt) - LBound(DenestedCrnt))
    Inx2 = LBound(DenestedCrnt)
    For Inx1 = 0 To UBound(Denested)
      Denested(Inx1) = DenestedCrnt(Inx2)
      Inx2 = Inx2 + 1
    Next
  Else
    Denested = DenestedCrnt
  End If

End Sub
Function GetCreateFldr2Full(ByRef Fldr1Root As Folder, ByRef Fldr1Full As Folder, _
                            ByRef Fldr2Root As Folder) As Folder

  ' Fldr1Root is a folder.
  ' Fldr1Full is a child of Fld1Root.
  ' Fldr2Root is another folder.
  ' The routine returns a reference to folder Fldr2Full where Fldr2Full's
  ' position within Fldr2Root matches the position of Fldr1Full's
  ' position within Fldr1Root.

  ' For example:
  '   If   Fldr1Root is      A->B->C
  '   and  Fldr1Full is      A->B->C->D->E
  '   and  Fldr2Root is      Z->Y->X
  '   then Fldr2Full will be Z->Y->X->D->E

  ' Fldr1Root, Fldr1Full and Fldr2Roor must exist.
  ' Fldr1Full must be a child of Fldr1Root.
  ' If either of the above conditions are not met, the routine returns Nothing.
  ' The routine will find Fldr2Full if it already exists or create it if it does not.

  ' Coded by Tony Dallimore

  Dim Fldr1FullNames() As String
  Dim Fldr1RootNames() As String
  Dim Fldr2Chld As Folder
  Dim Fldr2Crnt As Folder
  Dim Fldr2FullNames() As String
  Dim Fldr2RootNames() As String
  Dim InxFull1Crnt As Long

  Fldr1RootNames = GetFolderNames(Fldr1Root)
  Fldr1FullNames = GetFolderNames(Fldr1Full)
  Fldr2RootNames = GetFolderNames(Fldr2Root)

  If UBound(Fldr1RootNames) >= UBound(Fldr1FullNames) Then
    ' The full name is not longer than the root name so it cannot be a child
    Debug.Assert False
    Set GetCreateFldr2Full = Nothing
    Exit Function
  End If

  ' Match names within Fldr1Root and Fldr1Full to:
  '  * Check Fldr1Full is within Fldr1Root
  '  * Find "tail" that will have to be added to Fldr2Root to create Fldr2Full
  For InxFull1Crnt = 0 To UBound(Fldr1RootNames)
    If Fldr1RootNames(InxFull1Crnt) <> Fldr1FullNames(InxFull1Crnt) Then
      ' The root name does not match the start of the full name
      Set GetCreateFldr2Full = Nothing
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  ' UBound(Fldr1RootName) + 1 To UBound(Fldr1FullName) is the "tail" of
  ' Fldr1Full. Check there is an identical tail for Fldr2Root and, if there
  ' isn't, create it.
  Set Fldr2Crnt = Fldr2Root
  For InxFull1Crnt = UBound(Fldr1RootNames) + 1 To UBound(Fldr1FullNames)
    Err.Clear
    Set Fldr2Chld = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Fldr2Chld = Fldr2Crnt.Folders(Fldr1FullNames(InxFull1Crnt))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Fldr2Chld Is Nothing Then
      ' Fldr2Crnt.Folders(Fldr1FullName(InxFull1Crnt)) does not exist
      ' so create it
      Set Fldr2Chld = Fldr2Crnt.Folders.Add(Fldr1FullNames(InxFull1Crnt))
      ' Since folder did not exist within Fldr2Root, its children can't exist
      ' either. I could take advantage of this knowledge and not check existence
      ' of children but I think it is simpler not to.
    End If
    Set Fldr2Crnt = Fldr2Chld
  Next

  Set GetCreateFldr2Full = Fldr2Crnt

End Function
Function GetFolderNames(ByRef Fldr As Folder) As String()

  ' * Fldr is a folder. It could be a store, the child of a store,
  '   the grandchild of a store or more deeply nested.
  ' * Return the name of that folder as a string array in the sequence:
  '    (0)=StoreName (1)=Level1FolderName (2)=Level2FolderName  ...

  ' Coded by Tony Dallimore

  Dim FldrCrnt As Folder
  Dim FldrNameCrnt As String
  Dim FldrNames() As String
  Dim FldrNamesRev() As String
  Dim FldrPrnt As Folder
  Dim InxFn As Long
  Dim InxFnR As Long

  Set FldrCrnt = Fldr
  FldrNameCrnt = FldrCrnt.Name
  ReDim FldrNamesRev(0 To 0)
  FldrNamesRev(0) = Fldr.Name
  ' Loop getting parents until FldrCrnt has no parent.
  ' Add names of Fldr and all its parents to FldrName as they are found
  Do While True
    Set FldrPrnt = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FldrPrnt = FldrCrnt.Parent
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FldrPrnt Is Nothing Then
      ' FldrCrnt has no parent
      Exit Do
    End If
    ReDim Preserve FldrNamesRev(0 To UBound(FldrNamesRev) + 1)
    FldrNamesRev(UBound(FldrNamesRev)) = FldrPrnt.Name
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrPrnt
  Loop

  ' Copy names to FldrNames in reverse sequence so they end up in the correct sequence
  ReDim FldrNames(0 To UBound(FldrNamesRev))
  InxFn = 0
  For InxFnR = UBound(FldrNamesRev) To 0 Step -1
    FldrNames(InxFn) = FldrNamesRev(InxFnR)
    InxFn = InxFn + 1
  Next

  GetFolderNames = FldrNames

End Function
Public Function GetFolderRef(ParamArray FolderNames() As Variant) As Folder

  ' FolderNames can be used as a conventional ParamArray: a list of values. Those
  ' Values must all be strings.
  ' Alternatively, its parameter can be a preloaded one-dimensional array of type
  ' Variant or String. If of type Variant, the values must all be strings.
  ' The first, compulsory, entry in FolderNames is the name of a Store.
  ' Each subsequent, optional, entry  in FolderNames is the name of a folder
  ' within the folder identified by the previous names.  Example calls:
  '  1) Set Fldr = GetFolderRef("outlook data file")
  '  2) Set Fldr = GetFolderRef("outlook data file", "Inbox", "Processed")
  '  3) MyArray = Array("outlook data file", "Inbox", "Processed")
  '     Set Fldr = GetFolderRef(MyArray)
  ' Return a reference to the folder identified by the names or Nothing if it
  ' does not exist

  ' Coded by Tony Dallimore

  Dim FolderNamesDenested() As Variant
  Dim ErrNum As Long
  Dim FldrChld As Folder
  Dim FldrCrnt As Folder
  Dim InxP As Long

  ' See sub DeNestParamArray for an explanation of its purpose.
  Call DeNestParamArray(FolderNamesDenested, FolderNames)

  If LBound(FolderNamesDenested) > UBound(FolderNamesDenested) Then
    ' No names specified
    Set GetFolderRef = Nothing
    Exit Function
  End If

  For InxP = 0 To UBound(FolderNamesDenested)
    If VarType(FolderNamesDenested(InxP)) <> vbString Then
      ' Value is not a string
      Debug.Assert False     ' Fatal error
      Set GetFolderRef = Nothing
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  Set FldrCrnt = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
  Set FldrCrnt = Session.Folders(FolderNamesDenested(0))
  On Error GoTo 0
  If FldrCrnt Is Nothing Then
    ' Store name not recognised
    Debug.Print FolderNamesDenested(0) & " is not recognised as a store"
    Debug.Assert False     ' Fatal error
    Set GetFolderRef = Nothing
    Exit Function
  End If

  For InxP = 1 To UBound(FolderNamesDenested)
  Set FldrChld = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FldrChld = FldrCrnt.Folders(FolderNamesDenested(InxP))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FldrChld Is Nothing Then
      ' Folder name not recognised
      Debug.Print FolderNamesDenested(InxP) & " is not recognised as a folder within " & _
                  Join(GetFolderNames(FldrCrnt), "->")
      Debug.Assert False    ' Fatal error
      Set GetFolderRef = Nothing
      Exit Function
    End If
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrChld
    Set FldrChld = Nothing
  Next

  Set GetFolderRef = FldrCrnt

End Function
Public Sub GetNextMailItem(ByVal Action As String, ByRef MailItemNext As MailItem, _
                           ByRef MailItemFolder As Folder, _
                           ParamArray Params() As Variant)

  ' Each call returns the next mail item from the specified folder or folder list.
  ' It may be called repeatedly until all mail items in the specified folder or
  ' folder list have been returned

  ' On return, if MailItemNext is Nothing, there are no [more] mail items in the
  ' specified folder or folder list. Otherwise, MailItemNext is a reference to the next
  ' mail item and MailItemFolderName contains the name of the folder. See below for
  ' format of folder names used by this routine.

  ' * If Action = "I", the routine initialises itself and then returns the first mail
  '   item, if any, in the first specified folder.
  ' * If Action = "N", the routine returns the next mail item, if any, from its list of
  '   folders. Params() is ignored since values were stored during the Action = "I" call.
  ' * MailItemNext will be Nothing if no [more] mail items are present in the folder or
  '   folder list to search.
  ' * MailItemFolder is the the folder containing MailItemNext.
  ' * Params is only used if Action = "I"
  ' * Each value in Params, if any, is a folders to be searched for emails.  If Params is
  '   empty, every folder in every store will be searched for emails.

  ' Example uses:
  '
  '    Call GetMailItemNext("I", MailItemCrnt, MainItemPrntName)
  '    Do While Not MailItemCrnt Is Nothing
  '      ' Process mail item
  '      Call GetMailItemNext("N", MailItemCrnt, MainItemPrntName)
  '    Loop
  ' or
  '    Set FldrSrcRoot = GetFolderRef("outlook data file" & vbTab & "Inbox")
  '    Call GetMailItemNext("I", MailItemCrnt, MainItemPrntName, vbTab, FldrSrcRoot)
  '    Do While Not MailItemCrnt Is Nothing
  '      ' Process mail item
  '      Call GetMailItemNext("N", MailItemCrnt, MainItemPrntName)
  '    Loop
  '
  ' Coded by Tony Dallimore

  ' The routine uses three static variables:
  '  1) name of folder holding pending mail items
  '  2) collection MailItemsPending
  '  4) collection FolderSearchPending

  ' * The first part of the routine is only executed if Action = "I". It analyses
  '   the values in Params, if any, and initialises the static variables as
  '   appropriate.
  ' * The second part of the routine is a loop which is always executed. Each
  '   repeat of the loop:
  '    * If MailItemsPending contains any mail items, the first mail item
  '      is removed from the collection and returned to the caller in
  '      MailItemNext and MailItemFolderName.
  '    * if FolderSearchPending is empty, MailItemNext is set to Nothing
  '      and the routine exits.
  '    * The first folder in FolderSearchPending is removed from the collection
  '      and processed as follows:
  '       * If this folder contains mail items, they are added to MailItemsPending.
  '       * If this folder has any sub-folders, they are added to the beginning of
  '         FolderSearchPending.
  '    * The loop repeats to process the first new mail item, if any, or the next
  '      search folder, if any.

  Static FolderMainItem() As String
  ' Values in MailItemsPending are arrays with two entries. Entry 0 is a reference to
  ' the folder holding the mail item. Entry 1 is a reference to the mail item.
  Static MailItemsPending As New Collection
  ' Values in FolderSearchsPending are references to folders.
  Static FolderSearchsPending As New Collection

  Dim FolderChld As Folder
  Dim FolderChldNameStr As String
  Dim InxChld As Long    ' Index into child folders of folder
  Dim InxInsert As Long  ' Position within collection at which new
                         ' element is to be inserted
  Dim InxItm As Long     ' Index into mail items within folder
  Dim InxPrm As Long     ' Index into Params
  Dim FolderSearch As Folder
  Dim FolderSearchNameArr As String
  Dim FolderSearchNameStr As String

  If LCase(Action) = "n" Then
    ' Drop through to handle next mail item
  ElseIf LCase(Action) = "i" Then
    ' Code for Action = "I"
    If UBound(Params) = -1 Then
      ' No search folders specified
      ' Search every folder in every store
      With Session
        For InxChld = 1 To .Folders.Count
          Set FolderChld = .Folders(InxChld)
          FolderSearchsPending.Add FolderChld
        Next
      End With
    Else
      ' One or more search folders specified
      For InxPrm = 0 To UBound(Params)
        If TypeOf Params(InxPrm) Is Folder Then
          FolderSearchsPending.Add Params(InxPrm)
        Else
          Debug.Print "The " & InxPrm + 5 & "th parameter in the call of GetNextMailItem" & _
                      " is not a string. It should be a reference to a folder."
          Debug.Assert False      ' Fatal error
          Set MailItemNext = Nothing
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Else
    ' Invalid value for Action
    Set MailItemNext = Nothing
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Loop until have mail item to return or there are no [more] mail items to return
  Do While True
    If MailItemsPending.Count > 0 Then
      ' Extract values from first entry for return to caller and then remove first entry
      Set MailItemFolder = MailItemsPending(1)(0)
      Set MailItemNext = MailItemsPending(1)(1)
      MailItemsPending.Remove 1
      Exit Sub
    ElseIf FolderSearchsPending.Count = 0 Then
      ' No more folders to search
      Set MailItemNext = Nothing
      Set MailItemFolder = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    Else
      ' Extract first search folder, process and store results if any
      Set FolderSearch = FolderSearchsPending(1)
      FolderSearchsPending.Remove 1
      If Not FolderSearch.Parent Is Nothing Then
        ' This is not a store so it is a folder that could contain mail items
        For InxItm = 1 To FolderSearch.Items.Count
          If TypeOf FolderSearch.Items(InxItm) Is MailItem Then
            MailItemsPending.Add VBA.Array(FolderSearch, _
                                           FolderSearch.Items(InxItm))
          End If
        Next
      End If
      ' Now add any children to the start of FolderSearchsPending
      InxInsert = 1   ' Insertion point of first child folder
      For InxChld = 1 To FolderSearch.Folders.Count
        With FolderSearch.Folders(InxChld)
          Select Case .Name
            Case "Calendar", "Contacts", "Journal", "Notes", "Tasks", "RSS Feeds", _
                 "Conversation Action Settings", "Quick Step Settings"
              ' Ignore folders that cannot (should not?) contain mail items
            Case "Deleted Items"
              ' Ignore mail items deleted by user
            Case Else
              ' This folder can contain mail items
              If InxInsert < FolderSearchsPending.Count Then
                ' Insert new element before at least one existing element
                FolderSearchsPending.Add Item:=FolderSearch.Folders(InxChld), Before:=InxInsert
              Else
                ' Add new element after any existing elements
                FolderSearchsPending.Add FolderSearch.Folders(InxChld)
              End If
              ' Insert any further children after child just added
              InxInsert = InxInsert + 1
          End Select
        End With
      Next
    End If
  Loop

End Sub
Public Function NumberOfDimensions(ByRef Bounds As Collection, _
                                   ParamArray Params() As Variant) As Long

  ' Example calls of this routine are:
  '    NumDim = NumberOfDimensions(Bounds, MyArray)
  ' or NumDim = NumberOfDimensions(Bounds, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:E20"))

  ' * Returns the number of dimensions of Params(LBound(Params)).  Param is a ParamArray.
  '   MyArray, in the example call, is held as the first element of array Params.  That is
  '   it is held as Params(LBound(Params)) or Params(LBdP) where LBdP = LBound(Params).
  ' * If the array to test is a regular array, then, in exit, for each dimension, the lower
  '   and upper bounds are recorded in Bounds. Entries in Bounds are zero-based arrays
  '   with two entries: lower bound and upper bound.
  ' * If the array is a worksheet range, the lower bound values in Bounds are 1 and the
  '   upper bound values are the number of rows (first entry in Bounds) or columns (second
  '   entry in Bounds)
  ' * The collection Bounds is of most value to routines that can be pased an array as
  '   a parameter but does not know if that array is a regular array or a range. The values
  '   returned in Bounds means that whether the test array is a regular array or a range,
  '   its elements can be accessed so:
  '      For InxDim1 = Bounds(0)(0) to Bounds(0)(1)
  '        For InxDim2 = Bounds(1)(0) to Bounds(1)(1)
  '          :  :  :
  '        Next
  '      Next

  ' If there is an official way of determining the number of dimensions, I cannot find it.

  ' This routine tests for dimension 1, 2, 3 and so on until it get a failure.
  ' By trapping that failure it can determine the last test that did not fail.

  ' *  Params() is a ParamArray because it allows the passing of arrays of any type.
  ' *  The array to be tested in not Params but Params(LBound(Params)).
  ' *  The routine does not check for more than one parameter.  If the call was
  '    NumDim(Bounds, MyArray1, MyArray2), it would ignore MyArray2.

  ' Coded by Tony Dallimore

  Dim InxDim As Long
  Dim Lbd As Long
  Dim LBdC As Long
  Dim LBdP As Long
  Dim LBdR As Long
  Dim NumDim As Long
  Dim TestArray As Variant
  Dim UBdC As Long
  Dim UBdR As Long

  Set Bounds = New Collection

  If VarType(Params(LBound(Params))) < vbArray Then
    ' Variable to test is not an array
    NumberOfDimensions = 0
    Exit Function
  End If

  On Error Resume Next

  LBdP = LBound(Params)

  TestArray = Params(LBdP)

  NumDim = 1
  Do While True
    Lbd = LBound(TestArray, NumDim)
    'Lbd = LBound(Params(LBdP), NumDim)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      If NumDim > 1 Then
        ' Only known reason for failing is because array
        ' does not have NumDim dimensions
        NumberOfDimensions = NumDim - 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        For InxDim = 1 To NumberOfDimensions
          Bounds.Add VBA.Array(LBound(TestArray, InxDim), UBound(TestArray, InxDim))
          'Bounds.Add VBA.Array(LBound(Params(LBdP), InxDim), _
                               UBound(Params(LBdP), InxDim))
        Next
        Exit Function
      Else
        Err.Clear
        Bounds.Add VBA.Array(TestArray.Row, TestArray.Rows.Count - TestArray.Row + 1)
        Bounds.Add VBA.Array(TestArray.Column, TestArray.Columns.Count - TestArray.Column + 1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          ' I do not know how got here.  Investigate
          Debug.Assert False
          NumberOfDimensions = 0
          Exit Function
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        NumberOfDimensions = 2
        Exit Function
      End If

    End If
    NumDim = NumDim + 1
  Loop

End Function
```